# Amortize the debt problem

Tags: finance

Monthly payments are made on 130000 dollars at 5% for 25 days. Determine the payment needed to amortize the debt.

Comment: Do you really mean 25 days?  That would be less than one month's worth of payments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A useful formula is $P=R\cdot \frac{1-(1+i)^{-n}}{i}$, where $P$ is the size of the loan (principal); $i$ is the interest rate per period (not the annual rate); and $n$ is the number of interest periods over the life of the loan.

Comment: So here P=130000, I=0.05 and n=25. I have to solve for R?

Comment: It depends how interest is being compounded.  Usually compoundings match the payment period; here, monthly.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here is a slick way to calculate the amortization schedule for the debt.  I have made adjustment of the 25 day rate to monthly rate (actual over 360) and computed interest based on that.  Hope this is what  you meant.

Thanks

Satish